# opening/closing instance of Excel - process is still running in the background

Tags: excel, vb.net, process

I created an extract to excel in my vb.net applicatino. I write data to it, save it and then ask the user if they'd like to open it. The problem is, if they choose not to view it - excel closes down properly and it's not running in the processes - HOWEVER - when I view it in excel and then close it down - it's still running in the WTM processes. This is my code...

```
Dim FileNam As String = "C:\Me\" & ReportName & Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyyMMddhhmmtt") & ".xlsx"

If System.IO.File.Exists(FileNam) Then
   System.IO.File.Delete(FileNam)
End If
wBook.SaveAs(FileNam)
answer = MsgBox("Your extract has been saved here: " & strFileName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &
                        "Would you like to view the file?",vbYesNo)

If answer = vbYes Then
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FileNam)
End If
```

EDIT: I might add this is all within an TRY CATCH statement - this is the Finally part...

```
   GC.Collect()
   For Each proc In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
       If proc.MainWindowTitle.Trim() = "" Then
          proc.Kill()
       End If
   Next
```

Comment: the only thing that gets rid of the process is closing down the application! or Ending Process manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Killing a process is not a good idea for many reason, one of them is that you will kill also a instance of EXCEL that YOU have manually opened and you will lose your changes. If you want to keep this way, kill the process by a PID, and save the existing one when you start you app.

Or....

For close a Office Automation App, like Excel, Word, etc.. you must **dispose the COM object**.. try something like that:

```
oApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(True)
Application.DoEvents()
oApp.Quit()

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oApp)
oApp = Nothing
```

Where of course **oApp** is your Office `Application`.

You can also include **Garbage Collection** but is not a good idea...

```
GC.Collect() 'Start .NET CLR Garbage Collection
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() 'Wait for GC to finish
```

Comment: but it seems like this process it tied up to my application. If i don't open the excel app to VIEW it - then it's fine. It only stays running in the processes when I VIEW it. Then when I close my app excel disappears from processes.

Comment: Then zou must CLOSE your process after the code that you use for VIEW your excel. Write a function and call it when and where you need. ;)